# c++ Url Parser using boost regex match

Tags: c++, url, boost, boost-regex

how can i parse an url in c++ with boost regex 
like i have an url

```
http://www.google.co.in/search?h=test&q=examaple
```

i need to split the `base url www.google.com` and then query path `search?h=test&q=examaple`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure you need regex for that?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
  using namespace std;
  string x = "http://www.google.co.in/search/search/?h=test&q=examaple";

  size_t sp = x.find_first_of( '/', 7 /* skip http:// part */ );
  if ( sp != string::npos ) {
        string base_url( x.begin()+7, x.begin()+sp );
        cout << base_url << endl;
        sp = x.find_last_of( '/' );
        if ( sp != string::npos ) {
                string query( x.begin()+sp+1, x.end() );
                cout << query << endl;
        }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

---

regex version:

```
string input_string = "http://www.google.co.in/search/search/?h=test&q=examaple";
boost::regex exrp( "^(?:http://)?([^/]+)(?:/?.*/?)/(.*)$" );
boost::match_results<string::const_iterator> what;
if( regex_search( input_string, what, exrp ) ) {
    std::string base_url( what[1].first, what[1].second );
    std::string query( what[2].first, what[2].second );
}
```

Comment: i need the base of an url your code fails with this url
`http://www.google.co.in/search/search/?h=test&q=examaple`

Comment: @rajesh, fixed and added regex version.

Comment: Why do you escape the slashes in that regexp? You don't need to, it works without them