# Boost RegEx to parse url (RFC 1738) to extract domain name

Tags: c++, regex, boost

Can someone please post a regex to extract domain from a url confirming RFC 1738 (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt)?

**PROTOCOL://USERNAME:PASSWORD@DOMAINNAME:PORT/QUERYSTRING**

Example:

https://abc:password@answers.yahoo.com:777/question/index?qid=20100728205639

Thanks, 
Sumit

Comment: I think you should go ahead and summarize the character sets for the specific parts of the URL for someone with Regex experience to put a correct pattern together..

Comment: Hi Michael, I found a post "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624651/c-url-parser-using-boost-regex-match" to extract domain name but the regex doesn't work for other types of urls like:

Comment: https://abc:password@answers.yahoo.com:777/question/index?qid=20100728205639
http://answers.yahoo.com:777/question/index
https://abc:password@answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100728205639
http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100728205639
https://abc:password@answers.yahoo.com:777

Comment: I need a regex that can take care of all these scenarios

Answer (score 0):

You can find one such regular expression [here](http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls). You can probably simplify it, but that depends entirely on your needs.

You can also use a library which provides functions for parsing URLs. A good starting point is this Stack Overflow thread:
[Easy way to parse a url in C++ cross platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616011/easy-way-to-parse-a-url-in-c-cross-platform)